# How to set NODE_ENV to production while before webpack runs in package.json in windows

Tags: json, webpack

I am using windows 10 build and was wondering why this piece of code here does not work:

```
"build": "npm run clean && set NODE_ENV=production && webpack && gulp prod"
```

If I console.log the webpack it says that the node_env is in production, but it does not run the production code.

I have tried doing the command without the `&&` before the `webpack`, but in that case it doesn't even run webpack so I'm not sure I can do that. I have tried using a package called `npm-run-all` and seperating the commands then running them all together with a `parallel` flag with `npm-run-all`, but that did not work either.

Here is the webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = new require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
var chunks = ['app'];
var config = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    filename: 'bundle/[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle/[name].map'
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? [
          new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'commons',
            chunks: chunks
          }),
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            compress: {
              warnings: false,
              drop_console: true
            }
          })
        ]
      : [
          new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'commons',
            chunks: chunks
          })
        ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'images/',
          publicPath: config.server ? '/' : 'public/dist/',
          useRelativePath: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried e.g. [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)?

Comment: That is what I am doing now, I am not sure I can get it to work with the environment I am using, it is called turbo so I messing if I can use it or not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got `cross-env` to work, just need to make sure to install it as a dependency as well so the production stuff can use it. If you want post it as an answer let me know, otherwise Ill post the answer.